# How to make a dataframe from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dictionary and I want to make a dataframe from it.

This is my dictionary:

```
my_dictio = 
{'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': 
[{'Car': 'Mercedes', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'US', 'Owner': 'Richard', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type1', 'Payment': 'cash'}}},
{'Car': 'Audi', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE', 'Owner': 'Mesut', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type2', 'Payment': 'cash'}}}, 
{'Car': 'Volkswagen', 'Engine': 'Gas', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR', 'Owner': 'Paul', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type3', 'Payment': 'card'}}}]}
```

This is the code i'm using, when I run it I get `Car`, `Engine`, `Entity1` as columns:

```
dictio1 = my_dictio ['value']
df1= pd.DataFrame(dictio1)
```

**This is my expected result:**

[image]

I would like to learn and see where the fault is. Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the result you get?

Comment: It's because you have nested dicts. You need to explode those if you want them to appear as the screenshot you've posted.

Comment: this sort of operation expects a flat dictionary, so as far as it can tell you only have 3 columns, Car, Engine, Entity1

Comment: Hi Toti. The result I get is just 3 collumns (Car, Engine and Entity1). @ DBA108642 How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easier to just edit it in place, imo.

```
import pandas as pd

my_dictio = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': 
[{'Car': 'Mercedes', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'US', 'Owner': 'Richard', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type1', 'Payment': 'cash'}}},
{'Car': 'Audi', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE', 'Owner': 'Mesut', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type2', 'Payment': 'cash'}}}, 
{'Car': 'Volkswagen', 'Engine': 'Gas', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR', 'Owner': 'Paul', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type3', 'Payment': 'card'}}}]}

ok = my_dictio['value']

for i in ok:
    i['Type'] = i['Entity1']['Entity2']['Type']
    i['Owner'] = i['Entity1']['Owner']
    del i['Entity1']
    
df1= pd.DataFrame(ok)
```

Comment: you missed owner I guess

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
import pandas as pd

my_dictio = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value':
[{'Car': 'Mercedes', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'US', 'Owner': 'Richard', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type1', 'Payment': 'cash'}}},
{'Car': 'Audi', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE', 'Owner': 'Mesut', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type2', 'Payment': 'cash'}}}, 
{'Car': 'Volkswagen', 'Engine': 'Gas', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR', 'Owner': 'Paul', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type3', 'Payment': 'card'}}}]}

values = my_dictio['value']

car = []
engine = []
owner = []
car_type = []

for v in values:
    car.append(v['Car'])
    engine.append(v['Engine'])
    owner.append(v['Entity1']['Owner'])
    car_type.append(v['Entity1']['Entity2']['Type'])


df = pd.DataFrame({'car':car, 'engine':engine, 'owner':owner, 'car_type':car_type})

print(df)
```

Which outputs the following:

```
          car  engine    owner car_type
0    Mercedes  Hybrid  Richard    type1
1        Audi  Hybrid    Mesut    type2
2  Volkswagen     Gas     Paul    type3
```

Please note that `type` in python is a reserved keyword. I would stay away from using that...

Comment: good answer. you can use reference of dict instead of creating new lists.

Comment: you mean replacing the original contents of `my_dictio`?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
my_dictio = {'url': 'www.google.com', 'value': 
[{'Car': 'Mercedes', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'US', 'Owner': 'Richard', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type1', 'Payment': 'cash'}}},
{'Car': 'Audi', 'Engine': 'Hybrid', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'DE', 'Owner': 'Mesut', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type2', 'Payment': 'cash'}}}, 
{'Car': 'Volkswagen', 'Engine': 'Gas', 'Entity1': {'Country': 'FR', 'Owner': 'Paul', 'Entity2': {'Type': 'type3', 'Payment': 'card'}}}]}
```

**code:**

```
for row in dic['value']:
  owner = row.get('Entity1', {}).get('Owner')
  _type = row.get('Entity1', {}).get('Entity2', {}).get('Type')
  row.pop('Entity1')
  row.update({'Owner':owner, 'Type':_type})
  
df = pd.DataFrame(dic['value'])
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I think it is more effort to replace the contents of the dict than simply making new lists. This doesn't generalize well to highly nested dictionaries where you have to start grappling with deleting their contents....

Comment: you are not taking advantage of data structures which python providing.
And you are talking about the generality, suppose you have 100s of columns on first lever and need to extract only one element form second level. Will, you gonna create 99 new list :P. It was just an advice. It's a very crude way to code as you did. Never access dictionary using index should use get and other methods to avoid exception.

Comment: Suppose one row doesn't have an owner. what will your code do :P. Follow good programming practices :)

Comment: I recognize your use of `.get` is more robust. So your code won't break if one of the key value pairs is not available in the input dict. However, your comment about the 100s of columns doesn't really hold. Your code will also explode in that case, since you have to have 100 separate `get` calls in your `for` loop.

Comment: Accept or not you are overdoing in your code. only in case of 100s second-level objects. See my code carefully :)

Comment: I did look at your code. How would you generalize it for 100 columns then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220508/discussion-between-suryaveer-singh-and-user32882).

Comment: Thank you both. If I had enough reputation I would have entered the chat lol.